# How to get access to a dynamic nested json (as in I cannot know pre-determined values and keys) in a nested json

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, dynamic, nested

Greetings my fellow stackers.
I working on re-creating a minecraft build in unity (yes I do know about mineways that it is possible to do so via .obj -> .fbx) Why I want to do such things is simply because I want all of the blocks to be individual and simple for user to interact with (just input path to saved build and ta-daaam the build is in the unity project)
I am using WorldEdit in minecraft to save the build into a .schem file, which is then deserialzed using NbtLib from nuget and the export is a .json file.

**The problem**:
though the json file has some constant properties such as: "PaletteMax", "Width", "Height" and etc., there are also some dynamic values such as the block type: "minecraft:stone", "minecraft:bedrock".

**The question**:
Knowing that some values are dynamic, how would one access them and store them in variables for use in unity (I know this is mostly a c# question hence this question is on stackoverflow)

Sample code of the json file:

```
{
  "PaletteMax": 2,
  "Palette": {
    "minecraft:stone": 0,
    "minecraft:bedrock": 1
  },
  "Version": 2,
  "Length": 2,
  "Metadata": {
    "WEOffsetX": -3,
    "WEOffsetY": 0,
    "WEOffsetZ": -2
  },
  "Height": 1,
  "DataVersion": 2975,
  "BlockData": [0, 1, 1, 0],
  "BlockEntities": [],
  "Width": 2,
  "Offset": [1, -52, 2]
}
```

Sample code from c#:

```
private void deserialize()
{
    using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(input_path + file_name + ".schem"))
    {
        var nbtData = NbtConvert.ParseNbtStream(inputStream);
        var dataObj = new RootNBT();
        var tag = new NbtCompoundTag();
        Debug.Log(nbtData.Count);
        foreach(var key in nbtData.Keys)
        {
            switch (key)
            {
                case ("Length"):
                    INbtTag value;
                    nbtData.TryGetValue(key, out value);
                    dataObj.Length = int.Parse(value.ToJsonString());
                    Debug.Log(dataObj.Length); // this would output as 2 since the Length property in json above is 2
                    break;
                case ("Palette"):
                    //this is the dynamic json part, can't access "minecraft:stone" without knowing its name
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Just in case here is the link to the [NbtLib](https://github.com/sguest/NbtLib) I was using to deserialize the .schem file to json

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution!!

So basically I treated the nested json as a separate json where I stored it in a variable and did the same thing i did with the root component. The only issue was that the parsed stream was of type NbtCompoundTag and the child json was of type INbtTag, so i just casted it to NbtCompoundTag and it worked!

```
var value2 = (NbtCompoundTag)value1;
```

^ this line solved the issue I had. Later i treated it like a dictionary where I can access keys of it

```
private void deserialize()
    {
        using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(input_path + file_name + ".schem"))
        {
            var nbtData = NbtConvert.ParseNbtStream(inputStream);
            var dataObj = new RootNBT();
            var tag = new NbtCompoundTag();
            Debug.Log(nbtData.Count);
            foreach(var key in nbtData.Keys)
            {
                switch (key)
                {
                    case ("Length"):
                        INbtTag value;
                        nbtData.TryGetValue(key, out value);
                        dataObj.Length = int.Parse(value.ToJsonString());
                        Debug.Log(dataObj.Length);
                        break;
                    case ("Palette"):
                        INbtTag value1;
                        nbtData.TryGetValue(key, out value1);
                        var value2 = (NbtCompoundTag)value1;
                        foreach(var paletteKey in value2.Keys)
                        {
                            Debug.Log(paletteKey);
                            INbtTag keyValue;
                            value2.TryGetValue(paletteKey, out keyValue);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).